# Linear operator, defining a function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am self studying linear algebra and I came across this question:
Let V be a vector space (of a finite dimension) , and let U1 , U2 be sub-spaces of V. Prove that if : dim(U1) + dim(U2)= dim(V)
then there exist a linear operator T: V-->V such that Ker(T)=U1 and Img(T)=U2.

I don't really know how to approach the question so any hint will be help.

English isn't my native language so I apologize for any bad grammar or spelling mistakes.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup:**

Let $\dim(U_1)=a$, $\dim(U_2)=b$, and $\dim(V)=a+b$

Let $U_1=span\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_a\}$ and let $(U_2)=span\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_b\}$.

Further, let us extend the basis for $U_1$ such that it is also a basis for $V$ as $V=span\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_a,u_{a+1},u_{a+2},\dots,u_{a+b}\}$

---

Now... let us define $T$ in the following way: We want $U_1=\ker(T)$ so

Let $T(u_1)=T(u_2)=\dots=T(u_a)=0$

Then, we want $U_2=Img(T)$ so

Let $T(u_{a+1})=v_1,~T(u_{a+2})=v_2,~\dots,~T(u_{a+i})=v_i,~\dots,~T(u_{a+b})=v_b$

Now, check that we can in fact uniquely identify a linear transformation based on how it acts on a basis of the domain, that the way we have defined $T$ will indeed have the entirety of $U_1$ as the kernel, and will have the entirety of $U_2$ as the image.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will definitely check :)